# Custom JsonConverter - revert to default implemetation for array properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a custom JsonConverter where I need to alter the default serialization and deserialization for certain properties. Looking at the deserialization:

I am overriding the `ReadJson` method like so:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
    {
        var propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            ...
```

I can then check the TokenType and if appropriate, do my custom work. This works fine for most types but if I have a property that is Enumerable and has been serialized as a JsonArray then I would like to use the default implementation for that property before continuing with my custom stuff.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the reader is positioned at a value, you can call [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize.htm), [`JToken.Load()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm), [`JArray.Load()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Load.htm) or [`JObject.Load()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Load.htm) to deserialize or load that value.  Generally I prefer doing that to making manual "atomic" reads, because it ensures that nesting is handled correctly and leaves the reader correctly positioned for the next item in the JSON stream.  Calling `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` with the appropriate type when positioned on a property value gives you the default implementation of deserialization for that property.

In fact, a simple way to write a [`ReadJson`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) method is to load the entire contents of the object into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then iterate through the properties:

```
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (var property in obj.Properties())
        {
            switch (property.Name)
            {
                case "Data2":
                    {
                        // For example
                        myClass.Data2 = obj.ToObject<List<double>>(serializer);
                    }
                    break;
                    // More cases as necessary
                default:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unknown property " + property);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to do that, you can read property-by-property and deserialize or load individual values:

```
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                var propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (propertyName)
                    {
                        case "Data1":
                            {
                                // Expecting a double value.
                                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float)
                                    myClass.Data1 = Convert.ToDouble(reader.Value);
                                else
                                {
                                    // Unknown value, skip or throw an exception
                                    JToken.Load(reader);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Data2":
                            {
                                // For example
                                myClass.Data2 = serializer.Deserialize<List<double>>(reader);
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Data3":
                            {
                                // Expecting a string value.
                                myClass.Data3 = JToken.Load(reader).ToString();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            {
                                // Unknown property, skip or throw an exception
                                var unknownValue = JToken.Load(reader);
                                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Uknown property \"{0}\" with value: {1}", propertyName, unknownValue));
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```